# Spring WebClient header from ReactiveSecurityContext

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm trying to set WebClient header value accordingly to the authenticated user, something like this:

`webClient.post().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, getUserIdFromSession())...`

and

```
public String getUserIdFromSession() {
  Mono<Authentication> authentication = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication);

  //do something here to get user credentials and return them
}
```

Should I store the required header value somewhere else? Because in reactive way, everything returns a *Mono*/*Flux* and I'm currently unable to use the authenticated user data as I have used it with Spring MVC. There I could just do `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you aren't just flatmapping the Authentication and then calling the webclient? You could also just return the `Mono<String>` from your method

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
.flatMap(auth -> webClient.post().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, auth.getUserId()).exchange();
```

Comment: Didn't knew of this approach, works like a charm, thank you!